# Using imap_open() to get gmail account message [getting error]

Tags: php, codeigniter, imap

I am using imap_open() function to get gmail inbox message .... I am not able to login   to gmail account .I am runing this in mac os on XAMPP server.

Code ->

```
  $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Friggin Server: ' . imap_last_error());
```

getting error

```
 Severity: Warning

Message: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX

Filename: controllers/mail.php

Line Number: 19
```

I search a lot but not found any helpful answer . I am stuck in this . Please help . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of errors here that are leading up to the root cause of the failure. In this case, imap_last_error might not return any useful information. A [suggestion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php#103762) I saw noted on the imap_open page of the PHP manual is to trace through [imap_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-errors.php) instead, as this will give you all the errors that have occurred since the request has started. This seems to be a common issue particularly with gmail, where denied access might not be directly due to imap (an unverified account, for example).

Try this instead:

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Friggin Server: ' . print_r(imap_errors()));
```

Might yield more information as to why your connection is failing.

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php#103762

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-errors.php

Comment: And what does IMAP errors print? Have you verified that port 993 is not blocked or firewalled on the server?